# How to get a distinct, case-insensitive list using Linq and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to get a case-insensitive list from the results of an entity framework query. I have the following:

```
 var myList = myEF.GroupBy(e => new { e.Code, e.Description })
            .Select(e => e.First())
            .ToList();
```

That gives me a distinct list, but it's case-sensitive. I need case-insensitive.

I figured I should be able to do something like this:

```
var myList = myEF.GroupBy(e => new { e.Code, e.Description }, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .Select(e => e.First())
            .ToList();
```

But that doesn't seem to want to work with the anonymous object.

Adding `.ToLower` or `.ToLowerInvariant` doesn't seem to work either. Nor does using `Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` instead of the `GroupBy`.

Seems there ought to be an easy way to do this, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: If you do case-insensitive, how do you ensure distinct-ness?

Comment: You can try `myEF.GroupBy(e => new { e.Code.ToLower(), e.Description.ToLower() })`

Comment: agree with @Mrchief, it should work

Comment: Per my initial post, "ToLower" nor "ToLowerInvariant" works.

Comment: Are your string culture specific? If so, then try `OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of  `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried various methods you said and all of them did fail. I got this working however:

```
var distinct = list.Distinct(new CaseInsensitiveComparer());

public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        return x.Code.Equals(y.Code, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               x.Description.Equals(y.Description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A obj)
    {
        return obj.Code.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Feel free to tweak to your needs.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N7S5Ot)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Was hoping for something more streamlined, but sure doesn't seem like that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need 2 passes for this query.

First query for the conversion to lowercase, second one for the grouping.

Only escapes would be that you could extract in uppercase immediately from Entity Framework.

Or with additional EF/LINQ features that are still under developement :(

Answer (score 0):

Messy, but it works:

```
private class StructuralTupleComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>>{

    private IEqualityComparer<T> _cmp;

    public StructuralTupleComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> cmp){
      this._cmp = cmp
    }

    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, T> t1, Tuple<T, T> t2)
    {
      return _cmp(t1.Item1, t2.Item1) && _cmp(t1.Item2, t2.Item2);
    }


    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T, T> t)
    {
      return _cmp.GetHashCode(t.Item1) ^ _cmp.GetHashCode(t.Item2)
    }
}
```

and then

```
var myList = myEF.GroupBy(e => new Tuple<String, String>(e.Code, e.Description),
                               new StructuralTupleComparer(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(e => e.First())
            .ToList();
```

and hope that in some point in the glorious future there will be a `static IGrouping GroupBy<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, U> groupingprojection, Func<U, bool> equalitytester)` extension method (for Great Justice)